# Preceding value utilization in SQL code without declare statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the value in 'Needed', I have the logic provided in image link below. Can someone please assist?

[image: Image for Logic]

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . I think you just want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(oh + ib - demand) over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by week) + demand
from t;
```

This takes into account the cumulative `oh` and `ib`, not just the first row.